# Quick sort implement by queue?

Tags: c, sorting, stack, queue, quicksort

Can I implement quick sort using queue? 
I found this article only https://www.quora.com/Can-we-use-a-queue-in-quicksort-in-C. 
Is this article correct? 
If yes, why does the textbook always implement quick sort by stack or recursive method only? 
Because the information about this question is rare, so I ask here.

Comment: I didn't look into the article. Questions on SO should be more or less self-sufficient. You could summarize its contents, and add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bad cache performance`

With stack, we have enough temporal locality, while with queue it is lost completely. We basically are trying to sort the array in breadth first search way in queue method.

**EDIT**(from Will Ness' answer): And larger arrays(>RAM), queue method won't even work, since it requires O(n) space for sorting an array of size n. While stack based method required only log n space. All theoretical time complexity of both of them is same.

Answer (score 0):

> why does the textbook always implement quick sort by stack or recursive method only

Because the essence of quicksort is that it is in-place, and sorting is achieved by repeated partitions of the same array that is being sorted.

The partitions are done from the top down, from bigger-sized portions of the array down to smaller and smaller ones.

If we use **stack** to manage the-work-yet-to-be-done, the **size** of that stack will be **logarithmic** in the array's size (if the partition being put on the stack is the bigger one, always). This is equivalent to depth-first traversal.

But if we'd use **queue** for that, it would be equivalent to breadth-first traversal, and the size of the queue would be **linear** (which is *exponentially* worse than logarithmic).

Comment: If the smaller partition is always put on the stack, then the stack size is guaranteed to be O(log n). (That's assuming an explicit stack and a loop in which after partitioning, one partition is stacked and the other processed.)

Comment: Sorry for the thinko, i fixed the comment too late. The assertion is easy to prove: each stacked partition is less than half the size of the previous one, so tbe total height is atmost logarithmic. In practice, it could be a constant, since the log of the number of elements to sort is limited by physical constraints. 60 would be way more than enough.

Comment: @rici are you sure it's the smaller that goes onto the stack? in the degenerate case this would lead to linear stack size, wouldn't it? I think it's the bigger one. let's take the case when it's sorted. if we put away the bigger partition, the stack size will be 1.

Comment: @rici you were right the first time, I think. when we put on stack the bigger ones, we have fewer of them there.

Comment: Yeah, damn, my mind usn't working today. You recurse into the smaller one and tail recurse into the bigger one. So its the bigger one on the stack.

Comment: @rici I *loop* over the smaller one and put on hold the bigger one. :) Thanks again for th ehint!

Comment: That's equivalent. The usual optimization uses the call stack rather than an explicit stack; it was translating from one to the other which left me confused. It now seems clearer but I think I still need coffee.